# Get a hold of the index in a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, indexing

I got this loop going through a list of albums:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Albums.Count; i++)
  {
 <div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Albums[i].AlbumCovers)
 </div>
```

Is it possible to get a hold if the `[i]`?

The `[i]` is an int representing the index and i would like to store it in a
variable if possible?

Thanks!

Comment: store it for every element of the model?

Comment: yes, for every loop in the model i would like to store the index.
The reason for this is that I want to pass the index as a parameter
in an actionlik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to store the index to create a link for a mode item. What you can do is generate an action link with each iteration of your model. Here is a sample for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Albums.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Record", "Edit", new {Id=i})
  }
```

Here Edit Record is the text for the link and Edit is the controller action name, the Id is the parameter to edit action of the controller.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you are asking, `i` is already a variable which contains an integer but you can do this if you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Albums.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Albums[i].AlbumCovers)
}
```

If you want to capture a variable for the album, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Albums.Count; i++)
{
    Album album = Model.Albums[i];
    @Html.LabelFor(x => album.AlbumCovers)
}
```

Comment: This code also give the result I was after. Thank you